# Accessing ARM Processor Memory Registers through NXC

Tags: nxc

Specific to the NXC (Not eXactly C) programming language. Is it possible to access the memory registers on the ARM AT91SAM7S256 processor? I'm trying to investigate the use of Timer Interrupts to schedule a sampling routine.

I do know it's possible with nxt-gcc, but I don't know enough about NXC to understand if it would work. Would it not be possible to run with interrupts since the firmware uses the blocking I2C to communicate with sensors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NXC creates bytecode for the standard (or NXC upgraded) NXT virtual machine. The idea of this virtual machine is to create an abstraction layer to prevent malicious low level calls such as accessing memory registers on the processor.

So, without a low level compiler, such access would not be possible.